# IMAP base64 encoded PDF corrupting on save

Tags: python, pdf, base64, imap

I wrote a script that will download any attachments from unread messages in a mail box.  The 'application/pdf' content type I'm not having any trouble with.
The base64 Encoded 'application/octet-stream' content type is giving me a time.

My code below moves the pdf to the requested path, but corrupted as 0kb.  Any assistance is appreciated.

```
try:
    if part.get_content_type() == 'application/octet-stream':
        payload = part.get_payload(decode=1)
        fp = open(os.path.join('C:\\Attachment_Downloader\\',
                               datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m%d%y%H%M%S")
                               + "_" + str(var_seq) + ".pdf"), 'wb')
        fp.write(base64.decodestring(payload))
        fp.close()
        logging.debug("File Decoded and Moved "+ part.get_filename())
except Exception as e:
    logging.debug("File Move Failed : " +  part.get_filename())
    logging.exception("message")
```

Comment: Have you looked at the contents being assigned to `payload`? Does it look like valid base64 encoded data?

Comment: @martineau I was decoding the payload twice.  I fixed that issue and code is working as expected.  Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out all by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I was decoding twice. 
I fixed my code to the below and it's working as expected:

```
try:
    if part.get_content_type() == 'application/octet-stream':
        payload = part.get_payload()
        fp = open(os.path.join('C:\\Attachment_Downloader\\',
                               datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m%d%y%H%M%S")
                               + "_" + str(var_seq) + ".pdf"), 'wb')
        fp.write(base64.decodestring(payload))
        fp.close()
        logging.debug("File Decoded and Moved "+ part.get_filename())
except Exception as e:
    logging.debug("File Move Failed : " +  part.get_filename())
    logging.exception("message")
```